# How to debug tests with karma.js + require.js

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I have a setup basically described here - http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html

Problem is that I can't see source files of my tests in Chrome dev tools. So I can't debug it. Adding `debugger;` works but it is very uncomfortable, almost unusable since I can't browse any other file except the one with `debugger;` currently fired

Seems like karma load files, parse them, wrap each test and then unload files before run.

Answer (score 1):

[ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate) has a grunt build that will put all your plain js files into a `build` directory for testing and debugging.

Take a look at the `Gruntfile` and `karma/karma-unit.tpl.js` for how this is done.

Running `grunt watch` will leave your browser in a state where you can debug all your tests. Just click the `debug button`, set your break point(s) and reload the page.

Suddenly, you are debugging any or all your js files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug your test deeply, this is generally an indicator of badly organized code or badly made unit test. If you follow a TDD workflow, taking small step will help you prevent any major issue with your code. I warmly recommend you watch this video: http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2013-10-03-javascript-testing-tactics.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email (it doesn't use Karma, but you should watch it for the workflow/the principles presented)

Then, if you really want to debug your test code, nothing beat the browser. As so, you should set up your test in a manner it can be runned both in Karma and the browser. We implemented this for [QUnit, Jasmine and Mocha on the Backbone-Boilerplate](http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2013-10-03-javascript-testing-tactics.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email). Feel free to base yourself on these settings to set up your own environment.

Comment: thx, good answer! But I will wait for a while. Hope there is a solution for `karma-runner` since I'm not happy with the idea of maintaining two test runners: 1)simple browser runner and 2) karma-runner